# issues with Identity and Authorize using Roles and Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

it's my first time implementing identity and are having issues with Roles.
I've created two roles (User and SuperUser). On startup I define to policy's (Basic, Super).

In the database the user has the correct Role, but when I do User.IsInRole("User") I get false.

Also after sign in the class attribute [Authorize] causes a redirect to Sign In.

A cookie is created, so it signs in ok.

[image]
Is there any other part I need to configure?

```
opt.Authorization(optn => 
                        {
                            optn.AddPolicy("Basic", p => 
                                {
                                    p.RequireRole("User");
                                });
                            optn.AddPolicy("Super", p => 
                                {
                                    p.RequireRole("User");
                                    p.RequireRole("SuperUser");
                                });
                        });

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromForm] string email, [FromForm] string password)
{
    var tmp = await this.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, false, false);
    string url = tmp.Succeeded ? Url.Action("Index", "Secure") : Url.Action("Index", "Assets", new { Error = 1 });

    return RedirectPermanent(url);
}
```

> **Update** I was calling app.UseAuthentication() in wrong order. When
>   running UseAuthentication before UseMVC it works

Comment: if you're redirected to signin, it sounds like the sign in isn't working. it's possible you don't have a password in the database or your code requires email confirmation etc. debug that part and verify it's not throwing an exception. as for the policy, i don't know 100% if you have it correct, but it seems odd that "User" is an allowed role for "Super."

Comment: first the sign in is correct and returns succeded, the cookie gets set, but if I try to browse to a controller with [Authorize] it redirects to Sign In.

Comment: What's the version of your ASP.NET Core ? if you're using the ASP.NET Core 2.1, please note there's a known issue that the Role feature is not enabled by default.

Comment: @itminus  the version is 2,2, hmm okei. but how do I enable the Role feature?

Comment: @TheRuler As far as I know, the Role is enabled by default in 2.2

Comment: hmm strange :/ must be something I'm missing

Comment: I sign in. the cookie get's set, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false